# Referencing Map Elements in SpEL - Spring FTP dynamic remote directory creation

Tags: spring-integration, spring-el

I'm using outbound-channel-adapter of spring integration ftp

```
<int-ftp:outbound-channel-adapter id="ftpOutAdapterAutoCreate"
session-factory="ftpSessionFactory" channel="outChannel"
remote-directory-expression="headers.['remotedir']" charset="UTF-8" />
```

In my java code i'm setting remote directory in header.

```
org.springframework.integration.Message<File> messageA=
org.springframework.integration.support.MessageBuilder
.withPayload(reqFile).setHeader("remotedir",  "/errorOrders").build();
```

Error message it is showing while deploying

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1049E:(pos 7): 
Unexpected data after '.': 'lsquare([)'
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no period when you are referencing an element of a `Map` (message headers are a `Map`). The syntax is `headers['remotedir']` (no dot before `[`).

Also, given your map key has no `.`s in it, you can also use `headers.remotedir`.

Comment: Dear Russel, Im trying to add remote directory expression from my java code. And the file poller is called two time for each file. Can you please help me.

Comment: You need to show your configuration and what you are trying to do - but it doesn't belong here, you need to ask it as a new question because it's unrelated to the syntax question above.

Comment: Can I have your gmail/skype id so that we can chat and share this problem?

Comment: No, but you can start a chat here if you want.

Comment: I've no access in chat room.

Comment: You need to get your reputation up to 20 to use chat so, as I suggested before, you should ask your new question as a... new question.

Comment: I have created new question "Spring Integration file poller - multiple times service activator is called". Can you please help me?